# UIAlertView is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, viewcontroller

I keep getting errors on Xcode, how do i help this?

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Here i get 'presentModalViewController:animated' is deprecated. First deprecated in IOS 6.0.

```
-(IBAction)SetMap:(id)sender {
```

Here i get 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

```
}
```

And after the curly bracket i get 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0.

```
- (IBAction)Aktiekurs:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.euroinvestor.dk/boerser/nasdaq-omx-copenhagen/novozymes-b-a-s/239698"]];
}
```

And at last i get 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting these warnings/errors because those methods have been removed from the code base. I'm guessing you're trying to follow along with an old tutorial.

You should also post more of your code. What you have shown us is not where your warnings/errors are.

For the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` use this instead.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

For `presentModalViewController:animated` use this.

```
[self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Finally, for your UIAlertView you should now be using a UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"title"
                              message:@"some message"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
            actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                      style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                    {
                      NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                    }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
            actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                    {
                      NSLog(@"OK action");
                    }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: That's all i have in ViewController.m, maybe its because i followed several old tutorials, but one of them i couldn't get to work properly. So i deleted the code i wrote. But that have nothing to do with it, right? :)
But i can send what i have in viewcontroller.h?

Comment: Where you say you're getting these warnings makes no sense. If this is all the code you have then how are you getting " 'UIAlertView' is deprecated" if your code isn't even using a UIAlertView. If you had this code in there previously, then removed it, I can see how the warnings could still remain. Do a clean and try rebuilding your project and they may go away.

Comment: Thank you for the help Beau. I did i clean rebuild and it worked.

Comment: No problem, be sure to click the tick on my answer if you found it helpful, and never mind the negative votes you got, I knew what you were talking about :)